# Generate sql report with tinyint field used to signify primary role or subrole?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to create sql for dataset that will pull user_name, role, and subrole.
users can have multiple roles or subroles assigned. What i want to do is have the query return the values where its a primary role as ROLE and the ones where its not primary as Secondary Role.
Just testing out with single user as example

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS 'User Name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(roles.role_name) AS 'Role',
  CONCAT(managers.first_name, ' ', managers.last_name) AS 'Manager',
  roles.primary
FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_roles
    ON users.id = user_roles.user_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_managers
    ON user_managers.user_id = users.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN roles
    ON user_roles.role_id = roles.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users managers
    ON user_managers.manager_id = managers.id
WHERE users.first_name LIKE"Dave%"
GROUP BY primary
```

This returns as example

```
User Name   Role                                            Manager         primary
Dave Jones  HR                                          Susan Smith         0
Dave Jones  Operations Manager,Administrator,Mail Room  Susan Smith         1
```

What i want to do is have the roles that have primary value of 1 show under field Role and want to have Subrole field that will showroles with primary value of 0 so result would look like

```
User Name   Role                                        Subrole       Manager       
Dave Jones  Operations Manager,Administrator,Mail Room    HR          Susan Smith
```

wont need to include that primary value field in the output. Any ideas how best to do this ?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Is `primary` really in the `roles` table? Shouldn't it be in `user_roles`, since a role can be primary for one user and secondary for another user?

Comment: ya it really is in roles, this was designed by a developer not a dba so im just working with what we have, the user_roles table has the user ids and role ids which the user ids then link back to users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a conditional expression in `GROUP_CONCAT()`. So the concatenation for the primary roles will only return the primary roles, while the concatenation for subroles should only return the secondary roles.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS 'User Name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE roles.primary WHEN 1 THEN roles.role_name END)) AS 'Role',
  CONCAT(managers.first_name, ' ', managers.last_name) AS 'Manager',
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE roles.primary WHEN 0 THEN roles.role_name END)) AS 'SubRole'
FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_roles
    ON users.id = user_roles.user_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_managers
    ON user_managers.user_id = users.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN roles
    ON user_roles.role_id = roles.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users managers
    ON user_managers.manager_id = managers.id
GROUP BY users.id
```